# Strange case of null pointer exception

Tags: java, database, nullpointerexception, prepared-statement, stringbuilder

I'm running a program that connects to a device which in turn sends me data.

The data comes in as a String and then I process it accordingly to make an attempt to store it  into my database using prepared statements.

I catch a null pointer exception that seems to come from the prepared statements. I figure this to be the problem because the exception goes away when I comment the code. Maybe I don't understand prepared statements as well as I think I do. Any suggestions please?

Here is most of my code:

```
String[] dataIn = new String[100];
int i, channel, state, theStamp, temp, temp2;
char first, second;
String[] toBinary = new String[100];
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(40);

static String hexToBin(String s) {
  return new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2);
}

public void run() {
    // Run as long as the thread is alive
    while (this.threadAlive) {
      try {
        // Attempt to connect to the device.
        if (super.connectToDevice()) {
          // Send the data command to the device. If it is a test device, send the TIME command, otherwise send the DATA command
          if (this.testDevice)
            out.println(COMMAND_TIME);
          else
            out.println(COMMAND_DATA);

          // Read and store the data returned from the device
          String data = in .readLine();



          //******//
          System.out.println("The data: " + data);

          //Splitting data into array
          String criteria = " ";
          if (data != null) {
            dataIn = data.split(criteria);
            toBinary[0] = hexToBin(dataIn[0]);
            System.out.println("This is dataIn[0] before binary " + dataIn[0]); //testing 
            System.out.println("This is toBinary[0] " + toBinary[0]); //testing
            temp = 0;
            temp2 = 1;
            for (i = 1; i < dataIn.length; i++) {
              if (i % 2 == 0) {
                toBinary[i / 2] = hexToBin(dataIn[i]);
                System.out.println("Binary in String: " + toBinary[i / 2]);
                try {
                  PreparedStatement ps = this.db.getConnection().prepareStatement(PreparedStatementStatics.INSERT_C1_DATA);

                  for (int j = 3; j < 27; j++) {
                    first = toBinary[temp].charAt(j);
                    second = toBinary[temp2].charAt(j);

                    System.out.println("Checkpoint first/second achieved.");
                    System.out.println("Temp = " + temp);
                    System.out.println("Temp2 = " + temp2);

                    if (first == second) {
                      sb.append(0);
                    } else {
                      sb.append(1);
                    }
                    //System.out.print("sb appends: " + sb);
                  }
                  temp++;
                  temp2++;
                  System.out.println("sb turns out to be " + sb);
                  channel = sb.indexOf("1", 0);
                  state = toBinary[0].charAt(channel);
                  System.out.println("Change occurred in channel " + channel);
                  sb.setLength(0);

                  ps.setInt(1, channel);
                  ps.setInt(2, state);


                  ps.addBatch();

                  ps.executeBatch();
                  ps.close();
                  ps = null;

                } catch (NullPointerException ex) {

                  System.out.println("Null Pointer Exception: Not enough data this time through");
                } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                  System.out.println("Out of Bounds Exception");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                  System.out.println("Something is wrong with SQL");
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
              } else {
                System.out.println("This should be a timestamp: " + dataIn[i]);
              }
            }
          }
```

*UPDATE*

Here is my console log when I run the code:

```
The data: 5ABFE000 2556923 52BFE000 2556b6a 5ABFE000 2556dfb 4ABFE000 2556f8e 4AB7E000 25570da 4ABFE000 2557225 4ABDE000 255739e 4ABFE000 255765a 4ABFA000 2557844 4ABF2000 2557959 4ABFA000 2557b36 4ABFE000 2557bc2 4ABFA000 2557d3f 4ABF8000 2557dc3 4ABFC000 2557f90 4ABFE000 2558013 4AB7E000 25582fa 4AA7E000 2558487 4AB7E000 25586f0 4ABFE000 2558772 
This is dataIn[0] before binary 5ABFE000
This is toBinary[0] 1011010101111111110000000000000
This should be a timestamp: 2556923
Binary in String: 1010010101111111110000000000000
Null Pointer Exception: Not enough data this time through
This should be a timestamp: 2556b6a
Binary in String: 1011010101111111110000000000000
Null Pointer Exception: Not enough data this time through
This should be a timestamp: 2556dfb
Binary in String: 1001010101111111110000000000000
Null Pointer Exception: Not enough data this time through
This should be a timestamp: 2556f8e
Binary in String: 1001010101101111110000000000000
Null Pointer Exception: Not enough data this time through
This should be a timestamp: 25570da
Binary in String: 1001010101111111110000000000000
Null Pointer Exception: Not enough data this time through
This should be a timestamp: 2557225
Binary in String: 1001010101111011110000000000000
Null Pointer Exception: Not enough data this time through
This should be a timestamp: 255739e
Binary in String: 1001010101111111110000000000000
Null Pointer Exception: Not enough data this time through
This should be a timestamp: 255765a
Binary in String: 1001010101111111010000000000000
Null Pointer Exception: Not enough data this time through
This should be a timestamp: 2557844
Binary in String: 1001010101111110010000000000000
Null Pointer Exception: Not enough data this time through
```

Comment: I see a batch of one, and I see you close the PreparedStatement.... which line is throwing NPE?

Comment: Please post your stack trace or error log so that it becomes simpler to understand or decode.

Comment: Any line of code related to the PreparedStatement seems to throw it. When I comment out those lines of code, my code executes all the way through.

Comment: I have updated the post with my console log

Comment: `catch (NullPointerException ex) { System.out.println("Null Pointer Exception: Not enough data this time through"); }` ===> Never do that, you lose all the valuable information by ignoring the exception. Remove that catch block, let your code throw a NullPointerException, read the stack trace and fix the problem.

Comment: @assylias you just stole my words. :)

Comment: Thanks @assylias, that's a good point. `PreparedStatement ps = this.db.getConnection().prepareStatement(PreparedStatementStatics.INSERT_C1_DATA);`  This line throws the exception. Any idea why?

Comment: where is db from? where is it allocated?

Comment: @KS7X that narrows down your issue: either `db` or `db.getConnection()` is null.

Comment: @Barodapride It comes from other source files. The program I am running has many files and the database has been updating properly from other information so far.

Comment: @assylias I'm trying to wrap my head around what you mean. My database has had success connecting in other instances so far. I can tell you that the table I'm trying to insert data in is null so far of course

Comment: `if (this.db.getConnection() == null) System.out.println("The database is null");`

Answer (score 0):

Can  you please break the statements as shown below, if possible please post your complete code. at least the db part.

To write it in a simplified manner. its easier to debug in your case.

```
  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
  String sql = "Your Query";
  PreparedStatement ps= conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  ps.setXXX;--> binding values
  ps.setXXX;
```